# PHP username validation return false all the time

Tags: php

My php code work perfectly fine with validating email but for username it return `false` the whole time. I just wonder how can i fix it?

PHP:

```
 <?php
include_once("db_connect.php");
// USERNAME
if(!empty($_POST['username'])) {
    $username = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'";
    $results = $mysqli->query($query);
    if($results->num_rows == 0)
    {
        echo "true";  //good to register
    }
    else
    {
        echo "false"; //already registered
    }
} else {
    echo "false";
}
?>
```

Html Form

```
    <div id="registerForm">
<h1>Register</h1>
<form action="" method="POST" class="registerForm form-horizontal">
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="username" id="username">Username:</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter a username">
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Email:</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<input id="email" type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your email - IMPORTANT">
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="password">Password:</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<input id="password" type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter a password">
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="confirmpassword">Confirm Password:</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<input id="confirmpassword" type="password" name="confirmpassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm password">
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="code">Code:</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<input type="text" id="code" name="code" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Register Code">
</div>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
</form>
</div>
```

and jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.registerForm').validate({
    onkeyup: false,
    rules: {
        username: {
            required: true,
            rangelength: [5, 20],
            remote: {
                url: 'core/check2.php',
                type: "post",
                data: 
                {
                        username: function() {
                        return $( "#username" ).val();
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        password: {
            required: true,
            rangelength: [5, 20],
        },
        confirmpassword: {
            required: true,
            rangelength: [5, 20],
            equalTo: password
        },
        email: {
            required: true,
            remote: {
                url: 'core/check.php',
                type: "post",
                    data: {
                        email: function() {
                        return $( "#email" ).val();
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        code: {
            required: true,
            remote: {
                url: 'core/checkcode.php',
                type: "post",
                    data: {
                        code: function() {
                        return $( "#code" ).val();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    messages: {
        username: {
            required: "Enter a username.",
            rangelength: "Username must be 5 to 20 character",
            remote: "Username have been taken"
        },
        password: {
            required: "Enter a password.",
            rangelength: "Password must be 5 to 20 character",
            remote: "Email have been taken"
        },
        confirmpassword: {
            required: "Confirm your password.",
            rangelength: "Password must be 5 to 20 character",
            equalTo: "Your password does not match"
        },
        email: {
            required: "Enter your email(NOT SPAM EMAIL).",
            remote: "This Email have been taken"
        },
        code: {
            required: "Enter your Register Code",
            remote: "Invalid Code"
        }
    }

});
});
```

Comment: No idea. Can you post a sample table structure?  I will say this though, that is code just waiting to be hacked.  How about "select count(*) from..." or better yet implement that as a procedure / function?

Comment: are you learning PHP for academic purposes? If not, i advice to use a framework like Symfony2 of Zend or....It will allow to escape from building everything from zero (things like validating forms, best manipulating POST requests....) instead of reinveinting the wheel. Additionnaly, MVC will make building your project quick

Comment: could you post file with form? there're two false statements, you cannot know which one is printed

Comment: I use jQuery validation's  remote method and when ever i type something. This php statement return false

Comment: @whitelettersandblankspaces let him know basis, without good knowledge about php, strong oop makes no sense

Comment: @JimmyRuan show form part of code

Comment: that's all? you said you use jQuery to check validation, where is it?

Comment: @kmlnvm, I said `....build project quickly`. If he has no deadlines and wants to learn starting from the basics (which is better for PHP career), then use things like `if(!empty($_POST['username']))`. It depends on what he needs and doesn't stop me from giving advice

Comment: dont worry, i have no deadline :D

Comment: Please to use kmlnvm answer and edit your question by removing all unecessary lines of code.

Comment: You put the id for username in the label, rather than in the input.

Comment: i put id identifier just then but it still returning false

Comment: `if($results->num_rows == 0)
    {
        echo "true";` you're checking if it's FALSE or equals nothing, you need to do `if($results->num_rows == 1)
    {
        echo "true";` or `if($results->num_rows > 0)
    {
        echo "true";`

Comment: I TRIED it still return false :/ 
here is an image of what it look like [link](http://imgur.com/qKo0uQc)

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything. Then if there isn't white space in the column, and that the column is long enough to accomodate the data. Plus, `$mysqli->error` to the query.

Comment: nope, no error at all. BTW how to add `$mysqli->error` in my query

Comment: `$results = $mysqli->query($query) or trigger_error("there was an error....".$mysqli->error, E_USER_WARNING);`

Comment: em.. i edit my php code and now it keep returning `true` :/

Comment: Be aware this code is vulnerable to SQL injection, XSS and CSRF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input id="username" type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter a username">
```

you missed id identifier, that's all

Answer (score 0):

You have repeated `id="username"` for `label` and you `input`. That your problem.